# Redirect undesirable domain in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a wordpress site that i want to run 2 hosts with 2 different domains.

Site in the first host with the domain example1.com works correctly but in the second host domain example2.com redirect to example1.com domain.

There is no set redirect in the .htaccess file.

DNS of each of the 2 domains are set up correctly.

My question is how should I get it which part of the program code is this redirects ?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177703/can-you-run-wordpress-with-multiple-domains-at-the-same-time-not-multisite there are also some plugins that clim to make this easy

Comment: i don't want use of plugin

Comment: first link should still work fine

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it